# Bootstrap footer - no se alinea al final

Tags: css, bootstrap, design

Estoy intentando hacer un footer para mi sitio web pero cuando lo implemento me queda debajo de los demás contenedores que ya tengo y no al final. He investigado en diferentes sitios y siempre me dicen que este código final es como debería de implementar el *footer*. Que es exactamente lo que no me esta dejando que se implemente de manera correcta? Saludos!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Registrate</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/registro.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                    data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                    <div class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                        <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container my-5">
        <div class="row bg-dark text-light py-4">
            <!--A lo peq 12, todo lo largo 12 -->
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
                <h2 class="mx-2">Agregar agencia</h2>
                <div class="form-group mx-3">
                    <label for="agencia">Nombre de la agencia</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="agencia" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                        placeholder="Ingrese el nombre de la agencia">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group py-2 mx-3">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Espacio</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group py-2 mx-3">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Espacio</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                </div>

                <div class="d-grid gap-4 pt-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Borrar</button>
                </div>
                </form>

            </div>
            <!--A lo peq 12, todo lo largo 12 -->
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
                <h2>Listado de agencias</h2>
                <table class="table table-dark table-striped">
                    <thead class="text-center">
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Cantidad</th>
                            <th>Item</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="text-center">
                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

  <!-- Footer -->
<footer class="page-footer font-small bg-dark">
  <!-- Copyright -->
  <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3 text-light">© 2020 Copyright:
    <a href="/"> link</a>
  </div>
  <!-- Copyright -->
</footer>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregar la siguiente clase a tu `footer`:

- **[fixed-bottom](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/position/#fixed-bottom)**: Dicha proiedad coloca un elemento en la parte inferior de la ventana gráfica, de borde a borde y aplica los siguientes estilos

```
position: fixed;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1030;
```

Dejando tu footer de la siguiente manera.

```
<!-- Footer -->
<footer class="page-footer font-small bg-dark fixed-bottom">
  <!-- Copyright -->
  <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3 text-light">© 2020 Copyright:
    <a href="/"> link</a>
  </div>
  <!-- Copyright -->
</footer>
```

Aca te dejo el resultado:

https://gorgeous-truffle-1c766f.netlify.app/

Comment: Gracias!! GmrYael

Comment: Si te funciono puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada!